# NSFetchedResultsController delegate exception

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an app which uses a table view to display a list of items form my core data. I am using a remote api and I am updating my content after pulling down the table view - this triggers a call to the API.

Data is retrieved, parsed and inserted/updated into my Core Data.

I am *sometimes* getting an error after saving my Core Data context... Note that I'm not using multiple threads for this and like I said it doesn't seem to always happen.

I am literally going quite mad. It seems this guy has a similar issue but I'm still unable to fix mine with his solution:
[CoreData error driving me crazy... CoreData: Serious application error. An exception caught from delegate of NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844326/coredata-error-driving-me-crazy-coredata-serious-application-error-an-excep)

Here is the full error:

```
2012-07-31 14:14:47.332 MyApp[2893:11303] 
*** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells], 
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableViewSupport.m:1133
2012-07-31 14:14:47.332 MyApp[2893:11303] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -
controllerDidChangeContent:.  
Attempt to create two animations for cell with userInfo (null)
```

**UPDATE**:

I have a predicate on my fetch request. In order to seem to be deleting objects previously downloaded from API and which are missing from the new JSON result. I am setting a hideFromUser flag, this is saved in my Core Data.

If this flag is YES then it doesn't appear in the table view. But if it's ok then it does. I am also updating info on that managed object should anything be changed. Is it possible that I have an object which was previously set to hide... and is now set to show, and it also had some new data, could this possible trigger a "cell should update" and a "cell should insert" ?

More I think about it less it seems to be relevant.

Here is how I am updating my data:

1) I set all relevant objects of the corresponding type to "hide form user" (NSPredicate ensures they don't show in Table View).

2) I get an NSArray from the JSON data.

3) Looping each item, my createABookOfClass:withJSON: method queries the core data for a book (using an ID from the json dictionary), if it doesn't find it, it creates a new one. Note: at this point the "hide from user flag" is reverted.

4) After all is done, I save.

```
[[DPLocalStore getInstance] hideFlagItemsOfType:NSStringFromClass([MyFavouriteBook class])];

NSArray * itemsJSON = [data mutableObjectFromJSONData];

[itemsJSON enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {     
    [[DPLocalStore getInstance] createABookOfClass:[MyFavouriteBook class]
                                          withJSON:obj];
}];

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL didsave = [[DPLocalStore getInstance] save:&error];
```

Maybe what is happening is a cell containing Object A has been updated, it's update: the hide flag has changed. thus I am getting into a situation where the NSFetchedResultsController's delegate wants to update that cell, and delete it also... since the predicate now doesn't correspond to this object... That sound very likely...

Comment: Can you post the code where you insert/update the data?

Comment: It really is just simple parsing a json array and creating a bunch of nsmanagedobjects, after the loop I save the context. Nothing special is occuring here. Maybe if I give you access to my BitBucket repo ? Maybe this two animations for one cell... I just had a thought, please check my updated question. thanks.

Comment: Het Martin, I should have posted some more code like you said, check my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I may have found the error, since I changed it I haven't experienced the problem so I am assuming that it's ok.

In my implementation of `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` I had this in the switch statement for `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove`:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    // Reloading the section inserts a new row and ensures that titles are updated appropriately.
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.section]
             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    break;
```

As it was used in an older project (which I was not part of), I assumed the entire `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` implementation was okay, since this really is more of a template rather then something you will do anything customised.

In consequence I didn't pay much attention to it until I was reading up about it again on the Apple developer site. And I noticed, in case of a `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` you must delete a cell, and insert the cell at the new path. Yet I had implemented without really realising - delete the cell and reload the section !

In effect I should and now have the following:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    break;
```

Like I said I've not had a problem since. Would love to know from anyone what inner workings would be responsible for this - the exception having been "Attempt to create two animations for cell".

Thanks for any interest.

Comment: I guess there's some tutorial or source code out there we both copied and used. Since this is boilerplate stuff... Apple also has the (correct) implementation here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This code is still wrong.  You're supposed to call beginUpdate and endUpdate around your tableview actions for insert/update/delete.  They nest those beginUpdate/endUpdates to time the synchronous table view animations.  This is why you got the duplicate animation error.

Comment: @Derek I had this very same issue even with the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls in `-controllerWillChangeContent:` and `-controllerDidChangeContent:` respectively. And the exception still arises. The solution provided is correct.

Comment: That's because putting them in -controllerWillChangeContent: and -controllerDidChangeContent: is the wrong place to put them.  You put them inside the       -controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:    So that it gets put in the correct order.  The will and did implementations are only called once for bulk changes and so therefore can't nest properly.  You must put them in the didChangeObject implementation.